# PHP Query LIMIT DESC not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql-limit

I am trying to get a list of highscores (top 10) of players that played my game.
Everything works except for one thing, the list isn't right.
The first 10 people are correct, but when i go to page 2 the list isn't further going done.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Variables Explain

```
$gamemode = "Endless"
$filter = "Score"
$startNum = Page1 = 0, Page2 = 10
$maxlimit = 10
```

Query:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, Gamemode, Name, Score, ContainersSaved, TimePlayed, Date, ScorePerMinute
FROM $dbName . `highscore`
WHERE Gamemode='$gamemode'
ORDER by `$filter` DESC
LIMIT $startNum, $maxlimit";
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: What about variable $startNum. Check it.

Comment: Could you please replicate your table with sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, i forgot to change the 'Score' field from varchar to an INT, so it was trying to Descend on string instead of INT.

Thanks to the tip Imaginaerum gave me :)

Comment: An SO answer is not the same as a comment

Answer (score 1):

If your Score field is varchar try: (or change it to INT)

```
$order=$filter;
if($filter=='Score') {
    $order="ABS($filter);
}
$query = "SELECT ID,Gamemode,Name,Score,ContainersSaved,TimePlayed,Date,ScorePerMinute FROM $dbName . `highscore` WHERE Gamemode='$gamemode' ORDER by $order DESC LIMIT $startNum, $maxlimit";
```

Comment: If i do this i get an error : Error 500 Internal Server Error, also i think you forgot an " in your code?